# 2 Windows Servers with same names with SQL server with same name causing confusion in ODBC drivers on third machine

Tags: sql-server, vba, dns, odbc

Here's what I have:

Machine #1: Windows 10, Computer Name: Prod1, SQL Server Instance:SQL1, Database name: Dbase1

Machine #2: Windows Server2012, Computer Name: Prod1, SQL Server Instance:SQL1, Database name: Dbase1

Machine #3: Windows 10 laptop, Name: Client1, VBA code in Excel that Read/Writes data on SQL server instance on Machine 1

Machine 1 and 2 have exact same name, sql server instance and database. None of the machines are on the domain but are connected through the local home network. I use my vba code embedded in Excel to communicate retrieve data from SQL Server on machine 1. I have never run Machines 2 at the same time or on the same network. Today I accidentally switched on Machine 2 and now my ODBC drivers/VBA code in my app on Machine 3 are confused and keep reaching for Machine2 even after I switched it off. Somewhere in the Machine 3 settings the connection information for Machine 1 and 2 got mixed up and I can't fix it. It keeps telling me that login time has expired. I can't seem to fix it even after rebooting all the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer IP address instead of Machine Name

Comment: Thanks that works as a temporary fix for 2 big reasons. 1. It's a DHCP address so it can change any time. 2. I have the server name in several places and this excel file with embedded code is used by many so I can't make all those temporary changes. But at least for now I can get my work done. Thanks again. Please let me know if there's some place in the computer where the machine names and their ip addresses are stored so I can clean that part of my laptop and maybe that will fix the problem.

Comment: Final Solution: This problem not only created confusion for VBA code embedded in excel command buttons but also SQL Server Studio and ODBC connections. In SQL Server I was able to connect to the server just fine but when I needed to connect to the same server to import/export data I would get connection error. Using the IP address in all cases worked. The suggestion to use IP address was invaluable albeit temporary. After 4 days of using this temp solution I accidentally found out that the problem resolved itself. I'm assuming windows internally reconciled its dns addresses etc.